# Extract all two numbers after a character

Tags: mysql

I want to extract two digit numbers after a dot ".". For example I want to extract 95 and 05 (two digits after dot) from this "03.95~06.05".
I am using following query but it does not give the result I need.

```
select substring("03.95~06.05",SUBSTRING_INDEX("03.95~06.05",'.',1)+1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SELECT SUBSTRING("03.95~06.05",'~',1) to get 03.95. then you can use
SELECT SUBSTRING("03.95",'.',1) to get 03 and then get 0.95 with SELECT "03.95" - "03".

You can repeat the whole process for the second number with SELECT "03.95~06.05" - "03.95". 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much Nicky